# CodeIgniter return Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've made an application in `CodeIgniter` this working in locally and now I want to try in on a hosting: `hostinger`. If you want see, [check](http://primodebug.esy.es/Calendario/) this.
Now the problem's that when the I perform the installation of the library I get the error on the bottom from the code below:

```
public function get_admin_role_id()
{
    $result = intval($this->db->get_where('ea_roles', array('slug' => DB_SLUG_ADMIN))->row()->id);
    print_r($result);
    return $result;
}
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: models/admins_model.php
>
> Line Number: 372

Now this code should be returned the id roles of admin that is setted to default to `1`. Now the installation is also involved in creating the structure of the tables and logging in phpMyAdmin seems that the database is still empty, perhaps this could be the cause of the problem? Can someone help me understand what's going on?

[Complete admin model](http://pastebin.com/kShtzzsK)

Comment: Check this line `$this->get_admin_role_id()))->num_rows();` because you return only int id form your function `get_admin_role_id`.

Comment: @Dillinger Are you trying to access the id from ea_roles in the function get_admin_role_id() ?

Comment: I've tried with Saty said: $this->get_admin_role_id()))->num_rows();
and this return 0

Comment: Yor are not able to `->num_rows()` from int value. With `num_rows()` you first perform the query, and then you can check how many rows you got.

Comment: check `public function delete($admin_id) {` this line `array('id_roles' => $this->get_admin_role_id()))->num_rows();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a good practice to use like this. We cannot ensure that the query will always produce a result it depends on database table. if `$this->db->get_where` returns no results then it cannot invoke the `row()` method and access the field `id`so it will raise an error.

So always do like this

```
public function get_admin_role_id()
{
   $result = $this->db->get_where('ea_roles', array('slug' => DB_SLUG_ADMIN));
   if($result->num_rows()==0){
     echo "Result not found!";
   } 
   else{
    $row = $result->row();
    $id = intval($row->id);
  }
}
```

Please make sure that this query have some result.

```
select * from ea_roles where slug='your_slug';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public function get_admin_role_id() {
    return intval($this->db->get_where('ea_roles', array('slug' => DB_SLUG_ADMIN))->row()->id);
}
```

If this doesn't return anything then you don't have such record in the database

Be sure to have all of your database setted up correctly. execute the following SQL query within your phpmyadmin

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `easyappointments`
--

--
-- Dumping data for table `ea_settings`
--

INSERT INTO `ea_settings` (`id`, `name`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 'company_working_plan', '{"monday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"tuesday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"wednesday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"thursday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"friday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"saturday":null,"sunday":null}'),
(2, 'book_advance_timeout', '30'),
(3, 'company_name', 'ABC Company'),
(4, 'company_email', 'info@abc-company.ea'),
(5, 'company_link', 'http://www.abc-company.ea'),
(6, 'google_analytics_code', '');

--
-- Dumping data for table `ea_roles`
--

INSERT INTO `ea_roles` (`id`, `name`, `slug`, `is_admin`, `appointments`, `customers`, `services`, `users`, `system_settings`, `user_settings`) VALUES
(1, 'Administrator', 'admin', 1, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15),
(2, 'Provider', 'provider', 0, 15, 15, 0, 0, 0, 15),
(3, 'Customer', 'customer', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(4, 'Secretary', 'secretary', 0, 15, 15, 0, 0, 0, 15);

--
-- Dumping data for table `ea_users`
--

INSERT INTO `ea_users` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `mobile_number`, `phone_number`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip_code`, `notes`, `id_roles`) VALUES
(1, 'John', 'Smith', 'info@abc-company.ea', '0123 4567890', '0123 4567891', 'Tst-Address 12', 'Tst-City', 'Tst-State', '012345', 'Test administrator record for this installation. ', 1),
(2, 'George ', 'Clayton', 'g.clayton@abc-company.ea', '0123 456 7890', '0123 456 7891', 'Tst-Address 12', 'Tst-City', 'Tst-State', '012345', 'This is one of the test providers. He will handle the quick services.', 2),
(3, 'Christina', 'Nickolson', 'c.nickolson@abc-company.ea', '0123 4567890', '0123 4567891', 'Tst-Address 12', 'Tst-City', 'Tst-State', '012345', 'This provider will handle the long services.', 2),
(4, 'Nicky', 'Rowland', 'n.rowland@abc-company.ea', '0123 4567890', '0123 4567891', 'Tst-Address 12', 'Tst-City', 'Tst-State', '012345', 'This is the only secretary of the app. She will handle the data of Christina.', 4),
(5, 'John', 'Doe', 'john.doe@abc-company.ea', NULL, '0123 4567890', 'Tst-Address 12', 'Tst-City', NULL, '012345', 'This is a test customer record.', 3);

--
-- Dumping data for table `ea_user_settings`
--

INSERT INTO `ea_user_settings` (`id_users`, `username`, `password`, `salt`, `working_plan`, `notifications`, `google_sync`, `google_token`, `google_calendar`, `sync_past_days`, `sync_future_days`) VALUES
(1, 'administrator', 'fa7fc34500cbed7c3546f8b223f10797f24ecc9ccbf0c2251c21ab965ebf19bf', 'e0a9e47fbf57babcf536e98bed783a9404b95b671cdcf9e391f68989fa3ac14f', NULL, 1, 0, NULL, NULL, 5, 5),
(2, 'g.clayton', 'a86f0c41be938c36eaedb3c4869c445fe8b7192188110f57bf86b55ac2252f05', '9b56eaa06cb0cc1c3bdce616291da4f53c2cc5d3449591bacb28099346333f05', '{"monday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"tuesday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"wednesday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"thursday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"friday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"saturday":null,"sunday":null}', 1, 0, NULL, NULL, 5, 5),
(3, 'c.nickolson', '7dcd5ed6a1cc42de678227aa8d528069761b218d181ff7ef446a49622c384782', '807349d6bacc35650205c66d664d4d414d150dec7f17dbba360752224bab73f4', '{"monday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"tuesday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"wednesday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"thursday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"friday":{"start":"09:00","end":"18:00","breaks":[{"start":"14:30","end":"15:00"}]},"saturday":null,"sunday":null}', 1, 0, NULL, NULL, 5, 5),
(4, 'n.rowland', '8cd1cc276a72f88e6d27372aecde8d87903a91fa33a6d2aceafbf2d110e4c9c2', '55b3a83cea1e3a5c4945fcb12a7621519705b3d09c4fa3408d912a832c8410a1', NULL, 1, 0, NULL, NULL, 5, 5);

--
-- Dumping data for table `ea_secretaries_providers`
--

INSERT INTO `ea_secretaries_providers` (`id_users_secretary`, `id_users_provider`) VALUES
(4, 3);


--
-- Dumping data for table `ea_service_categories`
--

INSERT INTO `ea_service_categories` (`id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES
(1, 'Quick Services', 'A collection of services that have small duration. '),
(2, 'Long Services', 'A collection of services that require more time. ');

--
-- Dumping data for table `ea_services`
--

INSERT INTO `ea_services` (`id`, `name`, `duration`, `price`, `currency`, `description`, `id_service_categories`) VALUES
(1, 'Best Quick Service ', 30, 50.00, '€', 'This is the best service and it requires only 30 minutes of your time!', 1),
(2, 'Another Q. Service', 45, 60.00, '€', 'This will be the best choice for someone that wants a balance between time and money.', 1),
(3, 'Best Long Service', 180, 100.00, '€', 'This long service will examine all the aspects of your problem. Definitely the best solution!', 2),
(4, 'Ungrouped Srv.', 45, 0.00, '', 'This category is not like the rest. It can''t be grouped. ', NULL);

--
-- Dumping data for table `ea_services_providers`
--

INSERT INTO `ea_services_providers` (`id_users`, `id_services`) VALUES
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 3),
(2, 4),
(3, 4);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: The table isn't created yet maybe bad configuration of php?

Comment: @Dillinger I have posted the SQL query you need to post it within your phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are trying to access the column **id** from the table **ea_roles**. If you want to access id only, no need to take all(*) the values, instead takes on **id**. Then update the function like this:

```
public function get_admin_role_id()
{
    $id = 0;
    $result = $this->db->select('id')->get_where('ea_roles', array('slug' => DB_SLUG_ADMIN));
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        $id = intval($result->row()->id);
    }
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: But the table is empty

Comment: Then you will get the id as 0. Here what you are expecting when table is empty?

Comment: The problem's that the config file not seems to insert the table

Comment: Can you make sure this is the problem: You have created table and have some values in it. Here you want to select values with a where condition rt?